# iterm - what's the key-combo to switch panes?

Tags: terminal, iterm, shortcut, keybindings

I've learned how to split my terminal windows with apple-d and apple-shift-d.  Its very useful.
How do I then switch between the two panes (see below) using the keyboard?
I know I can use the mouse but would like to know if there's a key combo to do it.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will let you navigate split panes in the direction of the arrow, i.e. when using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to split panes vertically, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will let you switch between the panes.

Note: <kbd>⌥</kbd> is the [alt] key

Comment: Is this something that can be configured? I notice that 88


⌘+→/← Will move me between tabs, but I would like to swap this with the default navigation for split panes, as I use them more frequently, and I use tabs rather infrequently.

Answer (score 23):

Here are some useful keyboard shortcuts for iTerm navigation:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> navigates among tabs.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+[number] navigates directly to a tab.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+[number] navigates directly to a window.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> navigates among split panes.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> navigates among split panes in order of use.

Answer (score 0):

I often find it easier to map <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+"number" to one of the panes. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to navigate the iTerm Preferences, then go to **Keys** > **Navigation shortcuts**. In "Shortcut to choose a split pane", choose <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+"number". Then if you have three panes, you can navigate to each of them with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> respectively.